# Vue computed() not triggered on reactive map

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a **reactive** around a map that's initially empty: `const map = reactive({});`, and a **computed** that tells if the map has a key "key": `const mapContainsKeyComputed = computed(() => map.hasOwnProperty("key"))`. The computed doesn't get updated when I change the map.

I stuck with this issue for a day and managed to come up with a minimum example that demonstrates the issue:

```js
<script setup>
import {computed, reactive, ref, watch} from "vue";

const map = reactive({});
const key = "key";

const mapContainsKeyComputed = computed(() => map.hasOwnProperty(key))

const mapContainsKeyWatched = ref(map.hasOwnProperty(key));
watch(map, () => mapContainsKeyWatched.value = map.hasOwnProperty(key))
</script>

<template>
  Map: {{map}}
  <br/>
  Computed: does map contain "key"? {{mapContainsKeyComputed}}
  <br/>
  Watch: does map contain key? {{mapContainsKeyWatched}}
  <br/>
  <button @click="map[key] = 'value'">add key-value</button>
</template>
```

I've read a bunch of stackoverflow answers and the Vue docs, but I still can't figure it out.

- why mapContainsKeyComputed doesn't get updated?
- if the **reactive** doesn't "track" adding or removing keys to the map, why the `Map: {{map}}` (line 14) updates perfectly fine?
- when I replace the map{} with an array[] and "hasOwnProperty" with "includes()", it works fine. How's that different?
- how do I overcome this issue without the ugly "watch" solution where the "map.hasOwnProperty(key)" has to be duplicated?

EDIT: as mentioned by @estus-flask, this was a VueJS bug [fixed in 3.2.46](https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/v3.2.46/CHANGELOG.md).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue reactivity needs to explicitly support reactive object methods. `hasOwnProperty`  is rather low-level so it hasn't been supported for some time. Without the support, `map.hasOwnProperty(key)` tries to access `key` on non-reactive raw object and doesn't trigger the reactivity, so the first `computed` call doesn't set a listener that could be triggered with the next `map` change.

One way this could be fixed is to either define `key` initially (as suggested in another answer), this is the legacy way to make reactivity work in both Vue 2 and 3:

```
const map = reactive({ key: undefined })
```

Another way is to access missing `key` property on reactive object:

```
const mapContainsKeyComputed = computed(() => map[key] !== undefined)
```

Yet another way is to use `in` operator. Since Vue 3 uses `Proxy` for reactivity, that a property is accessed can be detected by `has` trap:

```
const mapContainsKeyComputed = computed(() => key in map)
```

[The support for `hasOwnProperty` has been recently added in 3.2.46](https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/v3.2.46/CHANGELOG.md), so the code from the question is supposed to be workable with the latest Vue version.

`map` is not really a map. This would be different in any Vue 3 version if `Map` were used, it's supported by Vue and it's expected that `map.has(key)` would trigger reactivity.